# Validate JSON to a Particular Format

Tags: java, json

I Have a Json which may come from other application and i need to check it whether is is in particular format. The JSON template i have is as follows,

```
{
    "Types": {
        "Type1": {
            "attribute1": "value1",
            "attribute2": "value2",
            "attribute3": "value3",
            "recordList": {
                "record1": [
                    {
                        "field": "value"
                    },
                    {
                        "field": {
                            "subrecord1": [
                                {
                                    "subfield1": "subvalue1",
                                    "subfield2": "subvalue2"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "date": "2010-08-21 03:05:03"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to validate the JSON based on particular template or format.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/) for that. JSON Schema lets you describe the format of the object graph you expect to receive, and then software implementing it lets you validate what you receive against your schema. There's an OSS Java implementation called [`json-schema-validator`](https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator).

Comment: I just need to check the incoming JSON is inparticular format not the keys and values in it.

Comment: @tjkmr: JSON Schema doesn't check values (other than that they match the expected type). It checks that the JSON you've received is in the format you expect. So for instance, if you're expecting an object with two required properties (`name` and `description`), but you receive an object with just a `name` property, that wouldn't match your schema. If your goal is just to test that the JSON is valid (but could describe anything), any decent JSON library will tell you that when you try to parse it.